# Using QProcess to run a Shell script file

Tags: c++, qt, command, windows-subsystem-for-linux, qprocess

I've compiled a C++ program (using G++) and it generated a file that I'll call `shellScript.sh`.

Using `bash.exe` from [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), I can run it by going to the directory where `shellScript.sh` is in and typing in `./shellScript.sh`.

Instead of having to do all of that manually, is it possible to have a `runShellScript button`, which when clicked uses the `QProcess` class to open up (and keep open) a `CMD` or `PowerShell` window with a command entered into it that automatically runs `shellScript.sh`. The file, `shellScript.sh` is located here: `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/shellScript.sh"`

**Hyde's suggestion that I tried to implement**

`runPowerShellScript.bat` (runs `runBashScript.ps1`)

```
@echo off
powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File %~dp0runBashScript.ps1
pause
```

`runBashScript.ps1` (runs `shellScript.sh`)

```
wsl -e ./shellScript.sh
```

If I double click `runPowerShellScript.bat` on Windows Explorer that runs `runBashScript.ps1`, which runs `shellScript.sh` with no problems whatsoever

`helloWorld.bat` (used for test purposes)

```
@echo off
echo Hello world!
```

`runBatchScript button` code (runs Batch scripts)
I tested it and it ran `helloWorld.bat`. In a new Command Prompt window, I saw the message "hello world"

```
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QProcess>

void MainWindow::on_runBatFile_clicked()
{

    QString filePath =  QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/helloWorld.bat";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "/C";
    arguments << "start";
    arguments << filePath;
    arguments << "/K";

    QProcess proc;
    proc.start("cmd.exe", arguments);
    proc.waitForFinished();


}
```

The `runBatFile button` nonetheless failed to run `runPowerShellScript.bat` how I wanted it to. Looking at the images below, it fails to run a .bat file that runs a PowerShell script file for reasons unknown to me

What I saw
[image: What I see]

What I was hoping to see
[image: What I was hoping to see]

`runShellScript button` code (Almost works as I was hoping. It opens a PowerShell window up, puts it into Bash / WSL mode, and goes to the directory we want. I just don't know what I need to add to the code to make it run `shellScript.sh` from here. I know that if I manually inputted `./shellScript.sh` that would run it but again, I would like this to be done through code (upon clicking a button) if possible)
)

```
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QProcess>

void MainWindow::on_runShellScript_clicked()
{
// Can use either bash or wsl, it doesn't matter
    QString commandA = "wsl";
    QString commandB = "bash";

    QString filePath =  QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/runBashScript.ps1";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "/C";
    arguments << "start";
    arguments << "powershell";
    arguments << commandA;

    QProcess proc;

    proc.setWorkingDirectory(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
    proc.start("powershell.exe", arguments);
    proc.waitForFinished();

}
```

Comment: First try to do this from command line. I mean, open a cmd.exe, and write command which opens up a new Powershell  window and runs the shell script in it. Figure that out first, without involving  Qt .

Comment: To get forward, create a .bat file, which does what you want _when you run it by double-clicking_. You may need to ask a windows/bat file question if you can't figure it out yourself. Step 2 woud be tonuse Qprocess to run the bat file, and step 3 to get rid of the bat file.and do the same directly.

Comment: @hyde I tried to implement your advice but I seem to be using the QProcess class wrongly since it isn't doing what I'd like it to do (run the .bat file that runs the .ps1 file that runs the .sh file in this scenario). No PowerShell or CMD window appears to open up

Comment: @Publicallyvisiblename if you double click the bat file, does that open a console window?

Comment: @hyde Yes, it does (it opens a cmd.exe window and runs "shellScript.sh" in that window). In case it matters, "shellScript.sh" does take user input

Comment: Ok, then I think you need to run the bat file with `cmd.exe /something /something test.bat` from QProcess. That way cmd.exe will open the new command windows for the bat file. You should be able to test it to get the command right from command prompt, so you make it open that extra windows instead of running the bat file in the same window.

Comment: To open it in a new Window using CMD, I have to write
 "start [fileName.bat] "/K"

Comment: @hyde Just not sure why QProcess isn't doing what I expect it to do (I updated the code for the button and give it those same arguments). It does at least now open a CMD window up. In this folder, I can show you a screenshot of what I am seeing vs what I am expecting to see

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AkcO8igyaNXAlH997BDnvGjd23bZ?e=cQv15t

It's almost like QProcess is running the batch file successfully but not the PowerShell file even though if I double the click batch file it does that

Comment: I can confirm that QProcess is running .bat files successfully now in a new window. I tested this with a simple "hello.bat" file that contained this text `@echo off echo Hello world!`. It's just failing to run a .bat file that runs a .ps1 file even though if I double click the .bat file it does that with no issues

Comment: Well, now you maybe have enough details to ask a new question (or edit this one). I'm not using Windows PC  much, so can't really help further. Before editing, check out this: [mcve].

Comment: @hyde I added as much detail to the question as possible and indicated what I'm confused / uncertain about. Thanks for the help